# How do I dynamically add columns to a python data frame so that I can include high order terms for each variable in my data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to conduct some feature engineering for a predictive model. Right now I have 55 variables and I would like to look at higher order terms for each variable. I would like do adjust each variable from the square to the 15th power and then include them in my data frame with a column name (i.e. var1_15). I started to work on this in the code but was not successful. Is this the correct method or is there a better way?

```
for k, i in range(2,16): 
    colname = 'k_%d'%i     
    dataframe[colname] = dataframe['k']**i
print(dataframe.head())
```

Comment: what's the error that you are getting from the above code?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please share the full Traceback error.

Comment: The problem is in the loop iteration: `for k, i in range(2, 16)` is invalid because you're trying to iterate two vars (`k` and `i`) over a single iterator (`range(2, 16)`). What are the column names in your original DataFrame? You'll probably need two nested `for` loops, or [sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help:

```
i = 2
for col in df.columns:
    df['K_{}'.format(i)] = df[col] ** i
    i += 1
```

also , you cannot use your for loop , if your intantion is there is not difference between i and k , there is no resason to use both vars , (thats why also some of the logic
why python do not allow this) , if you do want 2 vars and 2 iterartors , consider using zip.

hope i helped